# I'm an Iranian citizen with Japanese passport, can I go to Japan (my place of birth) easily?

Tags: passports, japan, iran

I was moved to Iran when I was 5 from Japan. my father is Iranian and my mother is Japanese.  I recently got my new valid Japanese passport from the embassy of Japan in Iran. I also did the paperwork for Japanese nationality in embassy a few months ago but no response.
I'm turning 22 this year is this mean I lost my Japanese nationality? I will be 22 in August. also I can't renounce my Iranian nationality til the age of 25.

Comment: Have you reached your 22nd birthday yet? Also it seems to me if they sent you a Japanese passport after your declaration choosing Japanese nationality, they have sent you a positive response... But I may well be wrong.

Comment: When making [The Choice of Nationality](http://www.moj.go.jp/ENGLISH/information/tcon-01.html), which I assume you did, how did you deal with  **The method of renouncing the foreign nationalitiy** portion of the process? Have you successfully renounced your [Iranian Citizenship](https://en.mfa.ir/portal/viewpage/4008/citizenship)? Please add this information to your question.

Comment: Is it even possible to renounce Iranian citizenship, when not yet 25 years old (condition 1 in the Iranian Citizenship link)?

Comment: Jake: Many countries require you to _try_ to renounce another citizenship in such a situation, and that is enough.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I can't renounce my Iranian nationality til the age of 25. and I should choose the Japan nationality by 22 or I will loose it and this timing can't match.

Comment: @xngtng 4 months later I will be 22

Comment: My impression here is that it is important to make a **formel declaration to the Japanese officials** a) you desire to retain Japanese citizenship b) renounce Iranian when you can (at age 25). They will know of this law preventing you to do so now.

Answer (score 10):

**If you are a Japanese citizen, you will stay a Japanese citizen until you take an action that revokes it.**

Within two years of turning 22, you're *supposed* to declare if you want to stay Japanese or renounce your other citizenship, but the law has a provision that assumes you will stay Japanese if you do nothing:

> If you fail to make the choice of nationality within the above-mentioned period, you shall be deemed to have declared that you choose to be a Japanese national and renounce the foreign nationality

http://www.moj.go.jp/ENGLISH/information/tcon-01.html

That said, there is no reason to wait.  Go to the Japanese embassy, inform them that you wish to stay Japanese, and they will advise how to handle renunciation of your Iranian citizenship.  The fact that you can't formally renounce it until 25 should not be an issue, since there are some countries like Belgium where you can *never* renounce it.